# Getting r, g and b from hex

Tags: javascript, colors, hex

I have a hexadecimal color code.
How do I get value of r, g and b from it in javascript.
I tried many but none worked and I got errors.
Here is one of those which I tried

```
function cutHex(h) {return (h[0]=="#") ? h.substring(1,7):h}
function hexToR(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(0,2),16)}
function hexToG(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(2,4),16)}
function hexToB(h) {return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(4,6),16)}
```

It give error

```
Uncaught TypeError: cutHex(...).substring is not a function
```

Comment: May you show that code?

Comment: I dont have any code im asking

Comment: What happened to the code from _"I tried many but none worked and I got errors"_?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#RGB_Colors might also be of help

Comment: You have provided the functions and the error, which is good, but how are you actually *calling* the function?

Comment: var hex = '#FFFFFF';  varR = hexToR(hex);

Comment: Yes but what is `hex` in that example? Where does it come from?

Comment: See edit please its a variable holding the value of hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues with your code is that it just naïvely assumes that the input is in a valid format. Based on the error, it looks like you're not passing it a string at all. For example, `hexToR(123456)` would cause `cutHex` to return the *number* `123456`, which indeed does not have a `substring` function.

Validation is always a good idea. Particularly for user input, but even for programmer input.

It may also be a good idea to avoid repetition. Your code looks very "copy-paste" in that you have three different functions that all do the same thing, just with a different slice of the input.

With both of these in mind, here's something to try:

```
/**
* Convert a hex string from #RRGGBB (or RRGGBB) to its component parts
* @param {string} hex #RRGGBB or RRGGBB
* @returns {[number,number,number]} RGB values in range 0-255
*/
function hexToRGB(hex) {
    if( typeof hex !== "string") throw new TypeError(`hexToRGB: string expected, got ${typeof hex}`);

    const match = hex.match(/^#?([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})$/i);
    if( !match) throw new Error(`hexToRGB: #RRGGBB expected, got ${hex}`);

    // now you have red, green, blue in match[1], match[2] and match[3] respectively
    // they're still in hex though, so...
    return match.slice(1).map(h=>parseInt(h,16));
}
```

This function includes validation and will throw meaningful errors should you pass something invalid to this function, aiding in debugging. Note also the JSDoc that documents this function, and allows your IDE to automatically detect potential errors in some cases.

Comment: What, specifically, are you unsure about?

Comment: How to use this? I think its var rgb hexToRGB(hex); but it will I think return 255255255. How to get Individual r, g and b values?

Comment: You... You call it. Just like you're calling `hexToR` in your current code.

Comment: It returns an array of `[r, g, b]` values.